# How to refactor Optional.isPresent() + Optional.get () to Optional.ifPresent()?

Tags: java, lambda, refactoring, option-type

I have a code:

```
public interface A{
    default Optional<MyClass> getMyClass() { 
        return Optional.empty(); 
    }

    default boolean isPresent(){ 
        return getMyClass().isPresent();
    }
}

public enum MyEnum implements A{
    private MyClass someObject;

    MyEnum(MyClass someObject) {
        this.someObject = someObject;
    }

    //...
    @Override
    public Optional<MyClass> getMyClass() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(someObject);
    }
}
```

I would like to change this code into something like `Optional.ifPresent()`. I need this instead of `Optional.isPresent` + `Optional.get` which I have now.

I tried to do something like `Optional.ofNullable(someObject).ifPresent()` but I have no idea what should be placed in `ifPresent()` parameter to get same result as from above code.

EDIT:

From comments I understood that a solution is to change
`if(something.isPresent()){ //do something }` to 
`something.getMyClass().ifPresent(val -> //do something);`
in class where I use interface.

Comment: This code is good, you need to change it where you call `get`

Comment: Can you explain? I tried to do this `Optional.ofNullable(someObject).ifPresent()`

Comment: Well, you usually have something like `if(op.isPresent()) { val = op.get();/* do something */ }` which would change to `op.ifPresent(val -> { /* do something */ });`

Comment: When I call my code is something `if(something.isPresent()){ //do something }`. I should change here to `something.getMyClass().ifPresent(val -> //do something);`?

Comment: @allocer Never put more code into comments, update the question instead.

Comment: @GhostCat -  sorry, I going to do this.

Comment: I don’t understand exactly what you are trying to obtain with this; but for most uses I’d say you don’t want your `isPresent()` method at all. Rather, as @JornVernee said, let the caller do `myEnumInstance.getMyClass().ifPresent(obj -> { /* something */ });`.

Answer (score 1):

allocer,

**Case 1**

```
if(something.isPresent())
{ 
    //do something 
}
```

In this block you can work with not final variables, for example:

```
String myString = null;
if(something.isPresent())
{ 
    myString = "Hello";
}
```

**Case 2**

```
something.getMyClass().ifPresent(val -> //do something);
```

In this block you cannot work with not final variables, for example:

```
String myString = null;
something.getMyClass().ifPresent(val -> myString = "Hello"); // does not work
```

to fix it you need to use one element list:

```
final String myString[] = {""};
something.getMyClass().ifPresent(val -> myString[0] = "Hello"); // will work
```

If you have final object then you can invoke its methods to modify it:

```
final SomeClass object = new SomeClass();
something.getMyClass().ifPresent(val -> object.someMethod()); // will work
```

Also you can use method references:

```
class SomeClass {

    // ... 

    public void calculate(MyClass value) {
        // do something
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        something.getMyClass().ifPresent(this::calculate);
    }
}
```